# Django - Adding audio track to page

Tags: python, django, audio

I am running localhost for developing a website, Apache2 is my web server and I built the site using Django. I am interested in adding audio tracks to specific pages. I had another page that I would display images and I took the same approach for trying to get the audio tracks to play but have not had any success. The URL appears to be correct, is there anything I need to do for FileFields vs ImageFields. I am aware that there are a few jQuery plug-ins for playing audio, but I am new to Django and Web development so I would like to get this basic version working before I move on to more advanced methods.

Relevant code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Artist(models.Model):
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artistInfo = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.artistName

class Album(models.Model):
    albumName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Release Date')
    albumInfo = models.TextField()
    albumArt = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/albumart/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.albumName

  class Song(models.Model):
    songName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album')
    audio_track = models.FileField(upload_to="songs/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.songName
```

**specificsong.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="singlesong">
        <p>Name: {{ song }}</p>
    <p>Artist: <a href="/artists/{{ song.artist }}/">{{ song.artist }}</a></p>
    <p>Album: <a href="/albums/{{ song.album }}/">{{ song.album }}</a></p>
    <p><audio controls="controls">
        <source src="{{ song.audio_track.url }}" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from Radio.models import Song, Artist, Album

def SpecificSong(request, songname):
    song = Song.objects.get(songName = songname)
    context = {'song':song}
    return render_to_response('specificsong.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^songs/$', 'Radio.views.SongsAll'),
    (r'^songs/(?P<songname>.*)/$', 'Radio.views.SpecificSong'),
    (r'^artists/(?P<artistname>.*)/$', 'Radio.views.SpecificArtist'),
    (r'^albums/(?P<albumname>.*)/$', 'Radio.views.SpecificAlbum'),
    (r'^register/$', 'listener.views.ListenerRegistration'),
    (r'^login/$', 'listener.views.LoginRequest'),
    (r'^logout/$', 'listener.views.LogoutRequest'), 
    (r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
    (r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset'),
    (r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
    (r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
    (r'^profile/$', 'listener.views.Profile'),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py (abbreviated)**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/kyle/Downloads/Django-1.5.1/radioSite/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Can you give the specifics of what is not working? File uploads? The playback of the audio files? Any django, apache, javascript errors? Please also post your `urls.py`.

Comment: When I load the page, the player appears. But, if I hit play the player just stays at 0:00/0:00 as if the track has not been loaded. SO the Playback is not working. adding my urls.py shortly.

Comment: There are also no errors.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, just trying gather as much information as I can. Can you post the output for a single `<source src="{{ song.audio_track.url }}" type="audio/mpeg" />`, your `settings.MEDIA_URL` and `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`. Am I correct in assuming you want to upload an audio file to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` and have Apache serve these files? Can you confirm that the files you are uploading are being placed into the `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` directory?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your assumptions about the functionality of the site. And the files are being loaded where they should. In the HTML page the output from an example song page is <audio controls="controls"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="/media/songs/Silhouettes_1.mp3"></source></audio>. I'll put the information from the settings file in the original post shortly.

Comment: This line looks suspicous: `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT). Apache needs to be configured to handle any `/media/*` URL paths and not Django.

Comment: I think that line is an artifact from when I was using Django's development server. I don't think my current version uses it. I am going to experiment with removing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33418/discussion-between-scott-woodall-and-kizl)

Comment: I removed it, the website is unchanged. The audio still does not play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this problem in the future, here is a list of steps that might solve your problem.

1. Make sure the browser you are using supports the type of audio file you are using. (should be obvious, but I made this mistake)
2. Make sure the permissions are what they should be for uploading to/from your setup.
3. Confirm that the files, were properly uploaded to your media folder.
4. Restart your server.

These steps helped me, hopefully it will help others.